# How to fix "ARIA attributes must conform to valid values"?

Tags: html, validation, wai-aria

I am testing my website's accessibility compliance and got a message saying

> ["ARIA attributes must conform to valid values"](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/1.1/aria-valid-attr-value)

The line that causes the problem is pasted below:

```
<div class="media-item slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide00" style="width: 280px;">
```

Does anyone know exactly which line caused the problem and how it can be fixed?

Comment: are you sure the tool you're using to test accessibility actually follows the latest spec?

Comment: @zzzzBov I am using the Accessibility Developer Tools chrome extension, which is not quite up to date but also using the Axe chrome extension, which is updated Jan 30, 2018. This issue is related to WCAG 2.0 (A).

Comment: Does the parent element have a role of `listbox` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check that an element with`id="slick-slide00"` exists within your code